# Adding extensions to a stdlib class in a ruby on rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, initialization, ruby-std

where would I place additions to stdlib classes in a rails project? Let's say something like:

```
class Date
  def foo
    'foo'
  end
end
```

I thought about the initializer folder but it somehow felt wrong. Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite on the contrary, `config/initializers` is the right place to put this code. I usually create a folder there and put these extensions into separate files named by the name of the corresponding class (`date.rb` in your case).